Javascript Web Worker execution pauses after some time when the browser does not have the focus
I am trying to send regular heartbeats from the frontend in a javascript web worker (using Angular 15.2) but I noticed that its execution stops after some time, when the focus is not anymore on the browser (MS Edge here), or the computer screen is locked.
I used the following code in the Web Worker (I used Atomics.wait() to have a blocking wait, not some callbacks)
    const AB = new Int32Array(new WebAssembly.Memory({
                                               initial: 10,
                                               maximum: 100,
                                               shared: true,
                                             }).buffer);
    function sleep(t:number) {
        Atomics.wait(AB, 0, 0, Math.max(1, t|0));
    }

    let count = 0

    while (true)
    {
        count++;
        console.log("while background log " + count);
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        sleep (60000);
    }


And I can see it stops after some time in the console logs.
Here it stopped at 10:39:03PM around 1 hour after 1 locked the screen and resumed when I unlocked the screen in the morning):
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 98
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:32:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 99
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:33:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 100
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:34:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 101
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:35:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 102
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:36:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 103
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:37:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 104
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:38:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 105
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/12/2024, 10:39:03 PM
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 while background log 106
151.c4d77d78b4f4b23d.js:1 5/13/2024, 7:30:51 AM

Is there an explanation to this?
Another point to notice is that this behavior is not happening when I leave the developer tools panel open, the Web Worker does not get paused.
Is it driven by the browser only? Do we have some controls to prevent it to pause?

The short answer is no, browsers throttle background execution because it results in a better user experience especially on mobile. I would actually feel a little sketch about a native mobile app that did that while in the background. I might feel ok about a desktop app doing that, but even that would be very context-dependent. Are you sure you want this to be a website? I'm not saying it doesn't happen, I had this exact situation where there were stripped down linux boxes who's only purpose was to show a web UI with near realtime data, but it's kinda rare...
